# Why is my constexpr object not constexpr inside my function?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I wrote a class that can be initialized and copied at compile time and using the object outside my function works at compile time too. Now I want to pass my `constexpr` object to a function to do some calculations, but the compiler produces an error that my object is not a constant expression.

How do I have to write my function to use my `constexpr` object?

Using GCC 9.2, C++17, (CLion option to use C++20 activated)

Here is my class, my function and the main. Notice:not all definitions are given, since it would be to much code for a post.

```
template<std::size_t t1_skipPos, std::size_t t2_skipPos, typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr auto contraction(T1 tensor1, T2 tensor2){

    /*ERROR: tensor1 is not a constant expression*/
    auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, tensor1.indices_amount-2, 
         t1_skipPos, tensor1.indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());

    return sris_tensor1;

}


template<typename T, typename ... Args>
class tensorBase{

    private:
        std::array<T, positive_natural_compiletime_pow<DIM3, std::tuple_size<Args...>::value>()> data;

    public:
        //std::vector<T> data = {};

        std::tuple<Args...> myTypeTup;

        std::size_t indices_amount =  std::tuple_size<Args...>::value;


    template<typename ... Element>
    constexpr tensorBase(Element&&... input) : data{input...} {};

    /* copy constructor */
    template<typename Tensor>
    constexpr tensorBase(const Tensor &oldObj){

        data = oldObj.get_data();

        myTypeTup = oldObj.myTypeTup;

        indices_amount = oldObj.indices_amount;

    }
/*
    template<typename Arr>
    constexpr tensorBase(Arr&& array) {
        data = array;
    };
*/
    constexpr auto calculate_indices() const{

        static_assert((std::tuple_size<Args...>::value <= 5), "tensor has to many indices");
        //auto l = std::tuple_size<Args...>::value;
        return cartesian_product<DIM3, std::tuple_size<Args...>::value>();
        //return cartesian_product_to_vec<DIM3, sizeof...(Args)+1>();
    };

    template<typename D>
    constexpr auto get_element(D&& val) const{
        return data[val];
    };

    constexpr auto get_data() const{
        return data;
    };
};

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
using tensor = tensorBase<T, std::tuple<Args...>>;

int main(){
    constexpr tensor<double, up_t, low_t, low_t> tensor1(11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 55.0, 66.0, 77.0, 88.0, 99.0); /*OK*/
    constexpr tensor<double, up_t, low_t> tensor2(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9);/*OK*/
    constexpr auto copyObj1 = tensor1; /*OK*/
    constexpr auto indices = tensor1.indices_amount; /*OK*/
    constexpr auto indices1 = tensor1.calculate_indices(); /*OK*/

    constexpr auto sris_outside = save_recreated_index_sequence
        <0, tensor1.indices_amount-1,0,tensor1.indices_amount,2>(tensor1.calculate_indices()); /*OK*/

    constexpr auto contract = contraction<0,0>(tensor1, tensor2); /*Error*/

    return 0;
}
```

The error message:

```
   In instantiation of ‘constexpr auto contraction(T1, T2) [with long unsigned int t1_skipPos = 0; long unsigned int t2_skipPos = 0; T1 = tensorBase<double, std::tuple<up_t, low_t, low_t> >; T2 = tensorBase<double, std::tuple<up_t, low_t> >]’:

error: no matching function for call to ‘save_recreated_index_sequence<0, (tensor1.tensorBase<double, std::tuple<up_t, low_t, low_t> >::indices_amount - 2), 0, tensor1.tensorBase<double, std::tuple<up_t, low_t, low_t> >::indices_amount, DIM3>(std::array<std::tuple<long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, 27>)’
       61 |     auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, tensor1.indices_amount-2, t1_skipPos, tensor1.indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());
          |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int offset, long unsigned int N, long unsigned int skipPos, long unsigned int length, long unsigned int times, class Arr> constexpr auto save_recreated_index_sequence(Arr&&)’
       46 | constexpr auto save_recreated_index_sequence(Arr&& arr){
          |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    In file included from /home/martin/CLionProjects/tensor-library-v1/main.cpp:43:
 error: ‘tensor1’ is not a constant expression
       61 |     auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, tensor1.indices_amount-2, t1_skipPos, tensor1.indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());
          |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’
       61 |     auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, tensor1.indices_amount-2, t1_skipPos, tensor1.indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());
          |                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
error: ‘tensor1’ is not a constant expression
       61 |     auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, tensor1.indices_amount-2, t1_skipPos, tensor1.indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());
          |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’
       61 |     auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, tensor1.indices_amount-2, t1_skipPos, tensor1.indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());
          |                                                                                                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘sris_tensor1’
       63 |     return sris_tensor1;
          |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
 In function ‘int main()’:
error: ‘constexpr const void contract’ has incomplete type
      162 |     constexpr auto contract = contraction<0,0>(tensor1, tensor2);
          |                    ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What's the text of your error?  Is it a run time error or a compile time error?  You said "throws" which leads me to believe "run time", but this is constextr we're talking about, which leads me to believe "compile time"... so I clearly cannot choose the glass in front of me!

Comment: Also, what version of C++ are you using.  It makes quite a bit of difference as to what is or isn't legal.

Comment: Function parameter are **never** `constexpr`. Even a `constexpr` function must be callable at runtime so the compiler can not treat them as such.

Comment: @MarkStorer its a compile time error since i cannot initialize the variable contract. constexpr variables can only be initialized at compile time using a constexpr function in a constexpr context.

Comment: @MarkStorer C++17 with GCC 9.2 and CLions option to use C++20 is turned on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `tensor1` as template argument if you want to use it in a context that requires a constant expression. This is currently (C++17) only possible as reference:

```
template<std::size_t t1_skipPos, std::size_t t2_skipPos, auto& tensor1, auto& tensor2>
constexpr auto contraction(){

    auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, tensor1.indices_amount-2, 
         t1_skipPos, tensor1.indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());

    return sris_tensor1;

}

//...

constexpr auto contract = contraction<0, 0, tensor1, tensor2>();
```

This does however also require you to declare `tensor1` and `tensor2` as `static`, so that they have linkage. Otherwise they cannot be used as template argument and it makes the function unusable with non-`constexpr` variables.

Note that C++20 adds non-type template parameters of class type which may make the reference, and consequently also the requirement of linkage, unnecessary (by using `auto` instead of `auto&`), but that does not apply to your class in the *current* state of the C++20 draft, which requires all non-static data members of the type to be public. This requirement was recently changed, so current compiler versions might be implementing the less strict requirements of the previous draft version when using `-std=c++2a`, in which your class would have been valid non-type template parameter of class type.

You cannot use function parameters in a context that requires a constant expression. The fact that this context appears in another constant expression evaluation doesn't matter. A `constexpr` function must always also be a valid runtime function.

---

In the specific case of the shown code you can however instead make `indices_amount` a `static` member of the class and access that through the type, so that the state of the function parameters is never used in the constant expression context:

```
static constexpr std::size_t indices_amount = std::tuple_size_v<Args...>;

//...

template<std::size_t t1_skipPos, std::size_t t2_skipPos, typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr auto contraction(T1 tensor1, T2 tensor2){

    /*ERROR: tensor1 is not a constant expression*/
    auto sris_tensor1 = save_recreated_index_sequence<0, T1::indices_amount-2, 
         t1_skipPos, T1::indices_amount, DIM3>(tensor1.calculate_indices());

    return sris_tensor1;

}
```

---

Also note that it seems to make no sense that your `tensorBase` has a parameter pack as second template parameter. It is only ever filled with exactly one argument and it wouldn't work with any other number either. For example `std::tuple_size<Args...>` only works if the pack has exactly one element. I suggest you remove all the `...`s relating to `Args` in that class.

Comment: First of all, I am deeply grateful you helped me with my problem. Secondly, when passing both objects as template parameter I am able to use the objects class variables as template inputs without declaring them static! Wondeful! (Maybe a C++20 feature?)

Comment: @M.Mac This is however a rather constraint method. It can only work as long as the passed objects have linkage (i.e. are `static` or globals), will make it unusable at runtime and also only works as long as the types are *literal types*.

Comment: @M.Mac I noticed that, see edit of question. But then `Args` doesn't need to (and shouldn't) be a parameter pack.

Comment: That I should consider for the future! In my case, I am working with premade data and tensors with 3-4 indices so everything can still be hard coded :)

Comment: @M.Mac Nevermind. From what I can gather essentially the same restriction still applies. It should not work with `auto&` and non-static `tensor1` at block-scope, even in C++20. It may have worked on GCC with `auto` and without `static`, but that is transient. There was a recent change in the C++20 draft that would disallow your `tensorBase` as (non-reference) non-type template parameter, because it has non-public data members. This change probably wasn't implemented in GCC yet. see [P1907R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html).